# Excel help needed for search and fetch

Tags: excel, search

I have column **A** with city name and column **B** with state name. I need assessment rate in column **C**. In another sheet I have a list of more than 15,000 cities with states. the format is:

```
A          B          C
City       State      Assessment rate
```

I need to know how i can do this using formulas. I will be glad to paste this value in sheet 1 also, but I don't know if vlookup can do this. Please help...

```
A          B          C                          D          E          F
City3      State3     Assessment rate from F     City1      State1     31.11
                                                 City2      State2     31.11
                                                 City3      State3     31.11
                                                 City4      State4     31.11
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can access cells in another sheet with formulas using:

```
=Sheet#!CR
```

where # is the sheet number C is the column and R is the row.

It's pretty much the same as finding a cell in the same sheet just with the added `Sheet#!` before the cell you want.

**Edit**

It sounds like (though your question is not very clear) you want to remove duplicate information. If you have 5,000 rows of data in Sheet 1 and 15,000 rows of the same type of data in `Sheet 2`, I wouldn't move `Sheet 2` data into `Sheet 1` and place it to the right of all those columns. You already have appropriate column headings in `Sheet 1` so I would place that information below the 5,000 rows of data in `Sheet 1`.

Once you've done this, the new data may have potential duplicates and to remove duplicates just use the sorting functions within the Data tab.

[Microsoft: Filter Unique Values](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx)

If this isn't what you want, then please try to take a little more time to explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: the sheet 1 will have around 5000 city with state. the sheet2 has more than 15000 city with state. to make it simple, i am copying the whole data into sheet 1. now sheet 1 has column a b c d e f. abc are city state and assessment yet to be given.
and d e f are city, state , assessment rate
column def has data till 15000 but abc has only 5000. I need a formula to compare ab with de, and if match found should copy the g data with respective c data. any suggestion please

Comment: To clarify: Your sheet 2 has `A B C` with possible duplicate city/state/assessment values and you placed that data into `D E F` of sheet 1 to consolidate?

Comment: I am sorry, I have confused everyone in every possible way. let me startover. There is a list column a and b with city name and state respectively. There is three column D E F with city state and their respective assessment rate. If i put a city name and state name in a and b respective ly, i need to put a formula in C such that it fetches the data from F by comparing A,B with D, E.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: The solution with VLOOKUP is not straight forward and you might need to insert a column D, with a formula like

```
=CONCATENATE(E2;F2)
```

and copy down this formula and your rate is now in column G. And you can write a VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2;D:G;4;FALSE)
```

Option 2:
If you don't want to use this additional column you can use a matrix formula (you will need to read more about it, if really want to go this way) like

```
{=INDEX(F:F;MATCH(A2&B2;CONCATENATE(D:D;E:E);0))}
```

but the performance will be not really good in this solution, I think.

Comment: I am sorry, I have confused everyone in every possible way. let me startover. There is a list column a and b with city name and state respectively. There is three column D E F with city state and their respective assessment rate. If i put a city name and state name in a and b respective ly, i need to put a formula in C such that it fetches the data from F by comparing A,B with D, E.